# Does eclipse che allow users managemnt

Tags: cloud, bitnami, eclipse-che

I have created a machine on the cloud using BITNAMI running eclipse che, once i created it gave me a username:user and password:some random password , i wan't to ask if the account attached to that username/password can create other users 'since they say it is an admin account', each user should be bound to its workspace , and how can i do it , if that is not possible how can i make a collaborative environment for my team, 
Any thread or any path would be very usefull guys ,thank you guys!!

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned the account already created in the Bitnami Cloud Image has admin privileges and can create other users and everything you need to create a collaborative environment for your team.

You will find a lot of information about how to use Bitnami Eclipse Che at:
https://eclipse-che.readme.io/docs/usage-bitnami

Other useful links:

Bitnami Documentation for Eclipse:
https://docs.bitnami.com/general/apps/eclipse-che/

Eclipse Che Documentation:
https://eclipse-che.readme.io/docs/

Comment: i have read the those links so many times , and that why i came to stackoverflow for some help, but i can't find the topic that hits the spot no article talks about user management , makes me think even if eclipse che supports it

Comment: i need some tuto or guide through, i don't have screen that allow user creation or management